# Iterating over multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list within a list, and I am trying to iterate through one list, and then in the inner list I want to search for a value, and if this value is present, place that list in a variable.

Here's what I have, which doesn't seem to be doing the job:

```
for z, g in range(len(tablerows), len(andrewlist)):
    tablerowslist = tablerows[z]
    if "Andrew Alexander" in tablerowslist:
        andrewlist[g] = tablerowslist
```

Any ideas?

This is the list structure:

```
[['Kyle Bazzy', 'FUP dropbox message', '8/18/2011', 'Swing Trade Stocks</a>', '&nbsp;', 'Affiliate blog'], ['Kyle Bazzy', 'FUP dropbox message', '8/18/2011', 'Swing Trade Software</a>', '&nbsp;', 'FUP from dropbox message. Affiliate blog'], ['Kyle Bazzy', 'FUP dropbox message', '8/18/2011', 'Start Day Trading (Blog)</a>', '&nbsp;', 'FUP from dropbox message'], ['Kyle Bazzy', 'Call, be VERY NICE', '8/18/2011', '&nbsp;', 'r24867</a>', 'We have been very nice to him, but he wants to cancel, we need to keep being nice and seeing what is wrong now.'], ['Jason Raznick', 'Reach out', '8/18/2011', 'Lexis Nexis</a>', '&nbsp;', '-'], ['Andrew Alexander', 'Check on account in one week', '8/18/2011', '&nbsp;', 'r46876</a>', '-'], ['Andrew Alexander', 'Cancel him from 5 dollar feed', '8/18/2011', '&nbsp;', 'r37693</a>', '-'], ['Aaron Wise', 'FUP with contract', '8/18/2011', 'YouTradeFX</a>', '&nbsp;', "Zisa is on vacation...FUP next week and then try again if she's still gone."], ['Aaron Wise', 'Email--JASON', '8/18/2011', 'Lexis Nexis</a>', '&nbsp;', 'email by today'], ['Sarah Knapp', '3rd FUP', '8/18/2011', 'Steven L. Pomeranz</a>', '&nbsp;', '-'], ['Sarah Knapp', 'Are we really interested in partnering?', '8/18/2011', 'Reverse Spins</a>', '&nbsp;', "V. political, doesn't seem like high quality content. Do we really want a partnership?"], ['Sarah Knapp', '2nd follow up', '8/18/2011', 'Business World</a>', '&nbsp;', '-'], ['Sarah Knapp', 'Determine whether we are actually interested in partnership', '8/18/2011', 'Fayrouz In Dallas</a>', '&nbsp;', "Hasn't updated since September 2010."], ['Sarah Knapp', 'See email exchange w/Autumn; what should happen', '8/18/2011', 'Graham and Doddsville</a>', '&nbsp;', "Wasn't sure if we could partner bc of regulations, but could do something meant simply to increase traffic both ways."], ['Sarah Knapp', '3rd follow up', '8/18/2011', 'Fund Action</a>', '&nbsp;', '-']]
```

For any value that has a particular value in it, say, Andrew Alexander, I want to make a separate list of these.

For example:

```
[['Andrew Alexander', 'Check on account in one week', '8/18/2011', '&nbsp;', 'r46876</a>', '-'], ['Andrew Alexander', 'Cancel him from 5 dollar feed', '8/18/2011', '&nbsp;', 'r37693</a>', '-']]
```

Comment: You'd have to clarify what your data structure look like. Do you have only two lists, or do you have a list where each of its element is another list? And assuming there are multiple matches, do you want to collect all of them?

Comment: You could be looking for: `zip(range(len(tablerows)), range(len(andrewlist)))`. But still didn't understand what the code is trying to do. You should give some example input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> #I have a list within a list,
>>> lol = [[1, 2, 42, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 42, 8]]
>>> found = []
>>> #iterate through one list,
>>> for i in lol:
...     #in the inner list I want to search for a value
...     if 42 in i:
...         #if this value is present, place that list in a variable    
...         found.append(i)
... 
>>> found
[[1, 2, 42, 3], [7, 42, 8]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a list whose elements are lists, this is what I'd do:

```
andrewlist = [row for row in tablerows if "Andrew Alexander" in row]
```

Answer (score 1):

> for z, g in range(len(tablerows), len(andrewlist)):

This means "make a list of the numbers which are between the length of `tablerows` and the length of `andrewlist`, and then look at each of those numbers in turn, and treat those numbers as a list of two values, and assign the two values to `z` and `g` each time through the loop".

A number cannot be treated as a list of two values, so this fails.

You need to be much, much clearer about what you are doing. Show an example of the contents of `tablerows` before the loop, and the contents of `andrewlist` before the loop, and what it should look like afterwards. Your description is muddled: I can only guess that when you say "and then I want to iterate through one list" you mean one of the lists in your list-of-lists; but I can't tell whether you want one specific one, or each one in turn. And then when you next say "and then in the inner list I want to...", I have no idea what you're referring to.